# SQL Join/LeftJoin Statement Returning Null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to join two queries with this statement:

```
$item = Category::where('type', $item)
              ->leftJoin('inventory', 'inventory.id', '=', 'categories.id')
              ->get();

return View::make('general.buy')
                ->with('items', $item);
```

This is my view (this returns NULL):

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
  {{ $item->id }} 
@endforeach
```

**The problem is that if there is no inventory id value equal to the category id field, the query returns the id as NULL.**

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can solve it? I should also mention that I am new to laravel, so please keep that in mind when rating this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried join() instead of leftJoin() ? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: I tried that. It didn't return anything

Comment: inventory.id will only match categories.id once if they are both on auto_increment. you might wanted to do something along the lines of ('inventory.id','=','categories.invetory_id') ?

Edit, my mistake, it will match many times, but that join doesn't really make sense. You might want to consider something as what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.  It's more about what LEFT JOIN means.  You have two tables, inventory and category correct?  According to your query (or at least what I can tell) this will generate SQL simliar to

```
SELECT FROM category LEFT JOIN inventory on inventory.id = categories.id
```

This says, select ALL rows from category and if they have a match in inventory fill in the columns queried (inventory.id) then supply that value, otherwise return null in that column.

Given this seems to be a somewhat unexpected result to you, I can't help but notice that the naming convention seems slightly off (but I'm not as familiar with laravel).  I would assume that instead of merging on categories.id you would merge on **category.id** (which would seem to match the rest of the schema).

Based on what and how you're querying, the results appear to be correct.

Comment: I'm trying to use the join to join the data from the inventory table. But I don't want it to return null. How can I do that with regular SQL?

Comment: INNER JOIN would only return items that match in both.